# I can't select or delete a bone and this blue circle keeps appearing?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, edit-mode

https://postimg.org/image/m00rul0vp/

When I left-click in edit mode, a black outlined-blue circle appears with a red line. What I'm actually trying to do is simply to select a bone, left-click the coloured arrows to move it and delete some bones. Now, I can't even select a bone in edit mode.

Comment: Can you select Bones in the outliner? Are you using multiple input devices (tablet etc)?

Comment: Just a laptop. It's ok, it's solved now. Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have enabled [Skeleton Sketching](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/armatures/bones/editing/sketching.html). You can disable it in the properties region <kbd>N</kbd>

[image: skeleton sketching panel]

Comment: Geezus that seemed so obvious XD Thank you so much :)

Comment: Only obvious if you know what it looks like enabled.